# Из xml в java class

Tags: java, android, xml, классы

Всем привет, ребята!
Возможно вопрос глупый, но все же хочу знать. Есть какой либо инструмент, которым можно из XML файла ( файл разметки ) сделать java.class, тобишь, у меня есть xml фрагмент, мне его нужно сделать java классом, чтобы внешний вид был одинаковый. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приложения для android состоят в основном из двух частей: макет экрана и класс где прописана логика. Дальше немного [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout?hl=ru) про макеты:

> Макет определяет визуальную структуру пользовательского интерфейса,
>   например, пользовательского интерфейса операции или виджета
>   приложения.

Вы можете создать нужную вам разметку на экране для отображения нужной вам информации. Так же для поддержки можно использовать в качестве ресурсов [drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable) файлы с иконками, ресурсы [менюшек](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus?hl=ru)  и много чего другого. Чаще всего в процессе добавления активности в приложение вы при помощи мастера по созданию активности генерируете пару `класс-макет` и по итогу у вас будет макет который вы сможете изменить под ваши нужды и класс который называется активностью, где можно будет прописать логику поведения элементов макета. [Документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) про активность:

> Активность- это отдельная, сфокусированная вещь, которую может сделать
>   пользователь. Почти все действия взаимодействуют с пользователем,
>   поэтому класс Activity позаботится о создании для вас окна, в котором
>   вы можете разместить свой пользовательский интерфейс с помощью
>   `setContentView (View)`.

У вас в активности есть [метод](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(int)) который подключает созданный макет:

```
setContentView (R.layout.activity_main)
```

В документации про него говорится:

> Устанавливает содержание активности из ресурса макета.

Соответственно вы не можете сделать из макета активность и наоборот, так как это противоречит логике :) Есть вариант переиспользования одного макета на разных активностях - для этого используя вышеупомянутый метод можно установить ресурс разметки.

### UPDATE

После некоторого общения в комментах я понял что вы пытаетесь сделать, и с 200% уверенностью могу сказать - ТАК ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ НУЖНО. То что вы хотите сделать делается на базе RecyclerView с кастомным адаптером и своей разметкой. Вот два туториала [1](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) и [2](https://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-android-cardview-example-tutorial). Почему не делается - приложению по началу будет просто работать, если фрагментов будет 1-2 но если это будет типа как лента ВК и карточек будет десятки то приложение будет кушать память как хром на ПК (может вы хром делаете ?) ). Сделайте все через список и это будет нааамного удобнее. Возьмите разметку фрагмента и сделайте из нее разметку для элемента списка :)

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, дружище.

Comment: Можешь подсказать, каким образом один фрагмент можно вставить в два контейнера в одной активности. 
План такой : создал фрагмент, и сделал скролл в активности, создал несколько контейнеров. Нужно чтобы фрагмент можно было изменять ( textView,ImageView ) и вставлять в разные контейнеры

Comment: @ЕвгенийПоловинкин, если честно очень сложно понять логику :( если вы хотите один и тот же фрагмент показать в двух контейнерах одной активности то просто разместите их друг над другом и грузите туда фрагмент, но тогда нужно каким-то образом их отличать друг от друга

Comment: Вот через comit() не работает :(
Вообщем, с сайта парсю данные, они могут изменяться ( больше, меньше ), У меня подготовлен макет фрагмента для них. Вот типо ленты вконтакте. Все так же - cardView, но только вот сколько их надо я хз, поэтому нужно как то расставлять. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил)

Comment: @ЕвгенийПоловинкин, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо тебе дружище, не первый раз уже выручаешь. Спасибо :)

Comment: Слушай, друг,выручай. Сутки бьюсь. Сделал как ты сказал. Все отлично, как по маслу все идёт. Но встал с тем, что никак не могу изменять их. Тобишь, мне с сервера приходят ответы (retrofit). 10 штук. И мне нужно их всунуть card,которые я расположил. Как это сделать я знаю, но ответ может задержаться и вылетает ошибка. Каким способом можно задержать ответы? Извини,что без кода. Хотя бы примерный алгоритм,как сделать, что почитать. Все облазил, и вопросы задавал. 0 решений, 0 ответов.

Comment: лучше если вы опубликуете новый вопрос с логом ошибки и тем как именно вы грузите данные в список :)

Comment: Добавил новый вопрос)

Answer (score 2):

Для преобразования XML-разметки в Java-объект в API  android  существует класс `LayoutInflater`, метод которого `inflate()` и осуществляет такое преобразование, возвращая объект класса `View`. Подробнее об этом можно почитать в [этой статье](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/80-urok-40-layoutinflater-uchimsja-ispolzovat.html)

PS: для решения конкретной проблемы пользователя, задавшего вопрос, этот ответ не подходит, так как ему нужно использовать RecyclerView, но ответ на сам вопрос тоже не помешает